# matchAll Throws error when g flag is missing now?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

From the MDN docs it states

> matchAll only returns the first match if the g flag is missing.

But if you run this code:

```js
const regexp = RegExp('[a-c]', '');
const str = 'abc';
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(regexp), m => m[0]));
// Array [ "a" ]
```

in a recent version of chrome you get the following error:

> Error: undefineds called with a non-global RegExp argument

I'm on chrome version 80.0.3987.116

I'm not sure if this is a chrome issue or the MDN documentation needs to be updated.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll

Comment: It's worth noting that `matchAll` seems to have [quite poor browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_string_matchall) overall, so you might want to stay away from it for the time being.

Comment: just adding similar error in Typescript `TypeError: String.prototype.matchAll called with a non-global RegExp argument`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The information presented to you on MDN, in this instance, is wrong.

The Official ECMA Specification, *ECMA-262 as of February 15, 2020*( [See here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.matchall) ), states that if there is no `g` flag present, that `matchAll` should throw a **TypeError**.

See specifically **2.b.iii** below.

---

[image: matchAll MDN]

---

The error message is obviously fairly confusing with its phrasing, but still correct.

Comment: The MDN docs currently do say that `matchAll` will throw an exception if the `g` flag is missing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#regexp.prototype.exec_and_matchall

Comment: @gaitat that's all well and good, but that wasn't the case when this answer was written 4 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

The g flag at the end of the regexp is the tip.

For example, if `\<\<[\w\.]*\>\>` is my regular expression to find strings like `<<hello>>`, `<<everybody>>`, `<<hello.world>>`, then a function to get all matches looks as below code:

```
const matches = (input) => {
  const arr = [...input.matchAll(/\<\<[\w\.]*\>\>/g)]
  return arr
}
```

It's working fine

(Yes the repeating input in every item of the result array looks as too much).